best way to double-bend arrows smoothly
It is common in tikzcd to bend an arrow either left or right, but I'd like a way to do the following:
You have two vertices that are not aligned in either direction, and want an arrow between them that begins and ends with the same slope, either both horizontal or both vertical; possibly you'd want other angles too but I digress.
To do that you necessarily will need to change the curvature at some point.
It would be nice to have an option to do this.
We would need to specify at which angle/slope an arrow begins and ends, and where the change in curvature happens. (The latter might not be that important.)

For instance
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[drr, double bend, double r, double near end] \\
& & B
\end{tikzcd}

should look like


\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[drr, double bend, double dr] \\
& & B
\end{tikzcd}

should look like


\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[drr, double bend, double d, double near start] \\
& & B
\end{tikzcd}

should look like


Could this be added maybe as a command? (or commands?)
Thanks in advance!

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Your question is not clear. The question title suggests you look for the best way to smoothly bend arrows, but in your question, you essentially ask how to define specific styles. What exactly is your aim?

@hpekristiansen thanks for the comment. Consider though that what I wrote can't possibly be compiled in any way. I invented options for the sake of visualization.

@JasperHabicht I don't follow. When I said "smoothly" I meant in a mathematical sense, as in "smooth curve".

@Julián Well, it was just not fully clear to me what your aim is, but I think I got it more or less. If you want to have curves that are defined exactly (as in Bézier), then you could check the controls option which gives you a lot of control over the specificities of the curve, but of course you would need to calculate the controls for the curve somehow ... In the end, I think it is a trade-off between exactness and simplicity of implementation.

The text I wrote to you is a standard text to make new users realise the importance of a MWE(https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). It is your job to give a compileable example, so that a solution can be shown with that code. Obviously you need to leave out the non-compilable new code from this MWE. In the future please do not make other people search and guess the documentclass, usepackages and more just to show a solution.

This is maybe not a full answer, but note that you can make use of the options out and in that specify where the arrow exits and enters the nodes and that each take a value in degrees where zero degrees means to the right and going counterclockwise.
It would be easy to define some styles based on that if needed, I guess.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[drr, out=0, in=180] \\
& & B
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[drr, out=315, in=135] \\
& & B
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[drr, out=270, in=90] \\
& & B
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}


To have even more control over how the arrow is bend, you may want to look at the various PGF options to specify curves.
